# subclassing a message to add additional behavior

Tags: python-3.x, grpc-python

Not sure why this isn't working, I want to subclass a message and add additional behavior:

```
import data_pb2 as pb2

class Status(pb2.Status):
    def __init__(self, streamer, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.streamer = streamer

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
        self.streamer.send_update()
```

When someone changes the pb2.Status message I want send_update to be called.
This is the unhelpful error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 62, in <module>
    class Status(pb2.Status):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 126, in __new__
    descriptor = dictionary[GeneratedProtocolMessageType._DESCRIPTOR_KEY]
KeyError: 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that works.  When the message is updated I have a threading event and its set method gets called.

```
class Status:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = pb2.Status(*args, **kwargs)
        self.event = None

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'status' or key == 'event':
            super().__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            super().__getattribute__('status').__setattr__(key, value)
            super().__getattribute__('event').set()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == 'event' or item == 'status':
            return super().__getattribute__(item)
        else:
            return super().__getattribute__('status').__getattribute__(item)


event = threading.Event()
status = Status(version="1",
                )
status_streamer = StatusStreamer(status, event)
status.event = event
status.version = str(int(status.version) + 1) #this triggers set to be called inside setattr, which results in the threads in SatusStreamer to stream the update
```

It's a bit hacky but because we cannot subclass the message this is acceptable.  status is the message and event is the threading event, when those items are assigned and start they don't trigger the event being set. However, when any other attributes are assigned to it triggers the .set() which yields the update to the clients.

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered the unfortunate truth that we're not meant to extend the message classes:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

Protocol Buffers and O-O Design Protocol buffer classes are basically dumb data holders (like structs in C); they don't make good first class citizens in an object model. If you want to add richer behaviour to a generated class, the best way to do this is to wrap the generated protocol buffer class in an application-specific class. Wrapping protocol buffers is also a good idea if you don't have control over the design of the .proto file (if, say, you're reusing one from another project). In that case, you can use the wrapper class to craft an interface better suited to the unique environment of your application: hiding some data and methods, exposing convenience functions, etc. **You should never add behaviour to the generated classes by inheriting from them**. This will break internal mechanisms and is not good object-oriented practice anyway.